# python - Lottery Confirmation Program Questions

Tags: python

I'm working on a three-digit ticket matching program, and it keeps failing and I don't know what it is.
There is a three-digit lottery ticket.
It's supposed to be this way.

```
import random

theNumber = random.randint(0, 99) 

dumberNumber = int(input("Lottery number?(0- 99사이): "))

digit1 = theNumber // 10
digit2 = theNumber % 10

u_digit1 = dumberNumber // 10
u_digit2 = dumberNumber % 10

print("winning number", theNumber )

if (digit1 == u_digit1 and digit2 == u_digit2):
print("100.")
elif (digit1 == u_digit1 or  digit2 == u_digit2):
print("50.")
else:
print("no money.")
```

This is what I don't know.

If the lottery numbers that the user has match all three digits, he or she will receive 10 million won.
If the lottery number that the user has matches the two digits, he or she will receive 3 million won.
If one of the three digits matches, one million won will be given.
If one does not match, there is no prize money.

Write a program that generates a random number of lottery numbers and prints out how much the prize money is based on user input.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include in your post what errors (if any) you are getting.  What is the expected output and the actual output?

Comment: Also, please indent your program correctly. As written, it is syntactically invalid. And you only handle two digits - is there an error in the description?

Comment: sorry. I'll attach it. We only did 2 digits. I've been asking this question since there were errors since 3 digits.

Comment: don't calculate with these numbers, just use array indexing. convert the numbers to 2 or 3 characters by adding `0`'s in front, `00` is a valid ticket

Comment: digit1=theNumber//100
digit2=theNumber%100
Like this?
But I don't know the formula that matches the single digit number.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see how you will get 3-digit number. If ```theNumber``` were ```0```, then the first printer would show only one-digit number (```0```)! Even you only test two-digit number, this statement ```If the lottery numbers that the user has match all three digits``` doesn't make sense. Other than that, your code should be working fine if you indent the ```if-logic``` properly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a homework question. You can't just copy and paste the if condition and the way they get single digits from the previous 2-digit question (which is probably example in class). You have to think and create new way to get single digits from 3-digit based on what you learn about division and modulus in your class.

Comment: I see. I'm trying hard. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does work assuming you have the indentation correct (make sure the statement after an "if" is indented).

Also note that your random number can currently be only 1 digit (E.G 3), which I don't think is a valid lottery number. To fix this I suggest generating each digit seperately so you can control the number better.

I assume that you are looking for help implementing this with 3 digits instead of 2.

Using str() we can convert numbers to "strings", E.G str(123) = "123"

This is helpful for your case, as a string can have its digits "referenced" by the following

```
my_string = "123"

my_string[0] = "1"

my_string[1] = "2"

my_string[2] = "3"`
```

I suggest you try to use this knowledge to help in identifying how many matches you have by converting the numbers to strings, it will be easier to compare digits when both your numbers are strings. Below is an example solution, but I suggest you try to understand it yourself.

```
import random

#seed randoms to make sure they are random, uses current system time to generate random numbers
random.seed()

#get each lottery number digit seperately
lottery1 = str(random.randint(0, 9))
lottery2 = str(random.randint(0, 9))
lottery3 = str(random.randint(0, 9))


#build a string from the digits, E.G 1, 2 and 3 becomes "123"
lottery_num = lottery1 + lottery2 + lottery3

#note that I'm converting the user input to a str() instead of an int() as you did originally
dumberNumber = str(input("Lottery number?(0- 99사이): "))

#guess1 is the first digit, guess 2 is the second etc.
#note that this is not necessary -- you could just reference the string later in code instead of creating a variable
guess1 = dumberNumber[0]
guess2 = dumberNumber[1]
guess3 = dumberNumber[2]

print("winning number", lottery_num)

digits_correct = 0 #number of digits guessed Correctly
if guess1 == lottery1:
    digits_correct = digits_correct + 1 #if our digit matches, we increment by one
if guess2 == lottery2:
    digits_correct = digits_correct + 1 #if our digit matches, we increment by one
if guess3 == lottery3:
    digits_correct = digits_correct + 1 #if our digit matches, we increment by one
    
if digits_correct == 0:
    print("No numbers guessed correctly :(")
elif digits_correct == 1:
    print("1 number correct, $50 reward")
elif digits_correct == 2:
    print("2 number correct, $100 reward")
elif digits_correct == 3:
    print("3 number correct, $1000 reward")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It will help solve it.